# Unknown data format and how to handle it in PHP (data format close to JSON)

Tags: php, dataformat

Long time no here. I didn't write code for a while now and came across data format which is very close to JSON but it's clearly not and have some problems with encoding/decoding or just simply handling it somehow. The data I get looks as follows :

```
"Data"
{
    "name1"        "Name-1"
    "name2"        "Name-2"
    "info"
    {
        "info1"     "Info-1"
        "info2"     "Info-2"
        "test"
        {
            "number"        "5"
            "player1"
            {
                "name"      "xyz"
                "stats1"        "1"
                "stats2"        "2"
                "stats3"        "3"
                "stats4"        "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many possible ways to "jsonyfi" it usign `str_replace` with the right arguments in a `foreach` loop and order but I feel like there is a better way to do it in PHP then writing tons of code which can fail if some enexpected change will occur to the data I receive.

How I get my data and what I've already tried to turn it to readable data is:

```
  ob_start();
  $result = ftp_get($ftp_conn, "php://output", $value, FTP_BINARY);
  $fileSize = ftp_size($ftp_conn, $value);
  $data = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $fulldata = str_replace('"Data"', '', $data);
  preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/', preg_replace('/{}/', '', $fulldata),  $matches);


$keys = array(
          '"name1"',
          '"name2"',
          '"info"',
          '"info1"',
          '"info2"',
          '"test"',
          '"number"',
          '"player1"',
          '"name"',
          '"stats1"',
          '"stats2"',
          '"stats3"',
          '"stats4"');

      $counter = 0;
      $result = '';

foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $v) {
        if(in_array($v, $keys)){
          $result .= implode(array($v, ' : '));
        }
        else if($v == '{'){
          $result .= $v;
        }
        else if($v == "}"){
          $result .= implode(array($v, ' , '));
        }
        else{
          $result .= implode(array($v, ' , '));
        }
       $counter++; 
     }

    $firstEdit = str_replace(', }', ' }" ,', $result);
    $secondEdit = str_replace('" , ,', ',', $firstEdit);
    $final = $secondEdit;
    $final .= "}";
    $totalFinal = str_replace('}, }', '} }', $final);

    echo $totalFinal;
```

This is just an short example of the data and my spaghetti code. As I mentioned I am sure there is some clean and nice way to handle it without the risk that it won't work when some key or anything unexpected changes in the data itself. Please help.

Comment: A (not very sophisticated) approach using regular expressions: https://3v4l.org/tmtDM It only looks for keys and values that are of the “double quote, multiple non-double quote characters, double quote” format – so if either keys or data could contain an “escaped” double quote, it will fail. (But your example data doesn’t let us know what escaping would actually be used in such a case.) First I am looking for such an “identifier” followed by whitespace and a `{`, to insert the `:` between those, and then the same for two identifiers (key and value), plus a comma after those.

Comment: Only JSON doesn’t allow a comma after the _last_ such pair, so I’ll remove that in an extra step afterwards. This works for your given example data, but it can easily fail, if it contains any specific situation not covered by that. If the values could f.e. contain line breaks, then you will have to replace those with `\n`. I think a more sophisticated “parser” would need a _specification_ of the data format first, and not just a mere example.